# API for sending MMSs between phones and server in Python?

Tags: python, sms, mms

I wanted to send MMS/SMS messages between phones and a central server. Initially, I thought of Twilio but it looks like they don't support MMS messages.

Is their an API that I can use that supports both MMS and SMS? Preferably in Python but Java or Ruby are fine too.

Comment: Have you considered emailing to the email addresses provided by the carriers?  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_SMS_gateways -- note many of them support MMS.

Comment: I thought about that but that seems like an unsatisfactory workaround. I was really hoping for something like library.sendmessage('number', '/path/to/mms').

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for a similar service to [Twilio](http://www.twilio.com), there's [Mogreet](http://www.mogreet.com). I haven't used them personally, so I can't vouch for their reliability, but there seems to be a decent following.

Answer (score 0):

Ricky from Twilio here. I know your question is old but wanted to update for anyone that stumbles on this that we added support for MMS on long codes in the US and Canada last year.

If you want to send an MMS using our [Python library](https://www.twilio.com/docs/python/install) you could use this code:

```
message = client.messages.create(to="+12316851234", from_="+15555555555",
                                     body="Hello there!",
                                     media_url=['https://demo.twilio.com/owl.png', 'https://demo.twilio.com/logo.png'])
```

Or if you're looking for something a little more complicated, I'd recommend this post on how my good friend Greg [taught his dog to send him MMS selfies using Python and an Arduino Yun](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2015/03/how-my-dog-sends-selfies.html).